# How to parse a string with special symbols using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to convert a string to json object but I am not able to convert it. Because I am using a string with special symbols.I have to read queries from a JSON file . Here is the file I am using named it as **functions.json**.

```
[
{
    "function":"Promo1",
    "query1": "{%24and:[{\"createdOn\":{%24lte:\"1712086400000\"}},{\"country\": \"India\"},{\"Type\": \"App\"}]}",
    "query2": "{\"country\": \"India\"}"
}
]
```

In this file there are so many Objects.I have to read the file first then I will get function name dynamically I have to fetch appropriate function query from that object.So consider I want **Promo1** query from that Object. I am able to get this query1 field value.After that I will **unescape** the special symbols from query1 string so that I will **$** instead of **%24**. I am using this code to unescape string `var q1 = unescape(str_arry[0].query1);` .

After unescape **q1** is holding a string value which is `{$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]}` .I am using to convert this string to Object

```
  {$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]}
```

Due to $ symbol I am unable to parse with **JSON.parse** . I am getting this error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 1

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: That's not JSON. Best to fix whatever's *sending* that broken input

Comment: Yeah it's a mongoose query . It is in string type

Comment: This is not valid JSON. You could start with making it valid JSON. It's not `$` that is the problem but the lack of quotes.

Comment: I agree this is not a valid JSON my question is how I can convert it to JSON Object?

Comment: use `json_encode` (if using php) in the server in order to send valiud json string to client

Comment: Consider explaining your case. Usually you shouldn't have such string if you want to parse it with JSON.parse.

Comment: Yes usually we don't have such queries.But my requirement is I need to get dynamic queries from JSON file.

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe The problem is that the thing you listed *is not JSON*. If you want it to be parsed without problems, stick to the standard, https://www.json.org/ . And it requires to use quotes for keys. The *I don't want quote* requirement doesn't look practical. If you're able but don't want to do this, it seems like you put obstacles on purpose. Consider explaining your case, there could be better solutions. Why should it be a string if it's stored in a file? It could be JS file.

Comment: @estus I updated my question can you see the updated one?

Comment: I see. Is there a reason why you made `functions` JSON file and not JS? It could possibly be reasonable if it was stored in DB.

Comment: Yes.I tried with JS but it won't work.That's why I moved to JSON

Answer (score 2):

The string is not valid JSON because object keys are supposed to be quoted with double quotes, according to [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/)

A simple way to avoid this problem is to not store data as JSON in the first place. If `functions` is a part of the application, data could be stored as JS with all respective benefits, including looser syntax requirements:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    function: "Promo1",
    query1: {$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]}
  }
];
```

If it's crucial for `query1` to be a string (though 
this isn't the case here because `query1` is supposed to be converted back to object then), it can be stringified in-place, so the object stays readable:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    function: "Promo1",
    query1: JSON.stringify({$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]})
];
```

A proper way to store a query as JSON is to stringify it according to JSON specification. If writing valid JSON manually is a problem, it can be outputted as:

```
JSON.stringify({$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]})
```

Alternatively, any third-party JSON formatter can be used.

Comment: Yeah I can use but I have to keep this file in remote location.So I cannot use module.exports

Comment: Then you will have to write valid JSON because that's what we usually do if we want it to be parsed like valid JSON. It's also unclear why there was JSON inside JSON. `query1` could be an object and not a string.

Comment: Yeah I know . After reading from a file entire content is in string.So I cannot convert it to object

Comment: Then you convert entire content to an object with `JSON.parse`. This needs to be done only once. Data in the question requires you to do `JSON.parse` second time on `query1`, which seems to be unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

JSON needs all the property keys to be enclosed with quotes as well to be valid, so you need to change the json string into `{"$and":[{"createdOn":{"$lte":"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]}` before you can parse it.

Maybe mongoose has ways to do this, else your're stuck with string manipulation.

```js
var json_str = '{"$and":[{"createdOn":{"$lte":"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse( json_str );

console.log( obj );
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.But in end I don't want quote to $and and $lte

Comment: I am expecting output as it is **{$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]}**

Comment: My question would be WHY? It's functionally the same. If you don't want the quotes you either cannot use JSON.parse() or you have to remove the quotes again after parsing the object.

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe keys can be only $and and $lte?

Comment: @imudin07 I didn't get you?

Answer (score 0):

kindly test this might be solve your problem

```
{"$and":[{"createdOn":{"$lte":"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]}
```

Comment: Sorry!! I don't want quote to $and after converting to JSON Object

Comment: if this is mongoose query than its fine you don't need to remove the quote mongo will accept this

Comment: param = {
                '$and': [{ 'dated': { '$gte': new Date(strtdate).getTime() } }, { 'dated': { '$lte': new Date(enddate).getTime() } }]
            }
        }
     

        return await Devicelogs.find(param).count();

Comment: use ' instead of " just for checking

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem with the help of JSON.stringify() method.

```
let dataWith$ = { '$and': [ { 'createdOn': {'$lte':"1712086400000"} },
                             { 'country': 'India' },
                             { 'Type': 'App' } ] 
                }

let parsedData = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( dataWith$)); // It won't give you error
console.log( typeof parsedData ) // object
console.log( parsedData.$and) // [ { createdOn:{'$lte':'1712086400000'} },  { country: 'India' },  { Type: 'App' } ]
```

Comment: Can you give me solution to this **{ '$and': [ { 'createdOn': {'$lte':"1712086400000"} }, { 'country': 'India' },{ 'Type': 'App' } ] }**? By converting this to Object

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any requirement to `parse` it is already what you get after `parse` .

```js
var obj ={$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]};

console.log(obj);

console.log(typeof obj);
function getKeyVal(ob){
Object.keys(ob).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log("key > " +key +  " value > "+JSON.stringify(ob[key]));
})
}
getKeyVal(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for using special symbols in JSON keys it must be wrapped in double or single quotes. if you cannot change it manually,
you can convert using JSON stringify method.

```js
var convertToJson = {$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]}
convertToJson = JSON.stringify(convertToJson)
console.log(convertToJson)
```

and then you can parse the data as usual

```
console.log(JSON.parse(convertToJson))
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, you want to transform your object into a valid JSO-Object?

In this case you could parse a stringified version of your object like i did here:

```js
var obj = {$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]};

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(jsonObj);
```

---

an other soultion could be using eval insetad of JSON.parse():

```js
var objStr = [{
  "function": "Promo1",
  "query1": "{%24and:[{\"createdOn\":{%24lte:\"1712086400000\"}},{\"country\": \"India\"},{\"Type\": \"App\"}]}",
  "query2": "{\"country\": \"India\"}"
}];

var q1 = eval('(' + unescape(objStr[0].query1) + ')');
console.log(q1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is still string and keys are always like $and, $lte or $abc.
This can be a solution:

```js
var json_str = '{$and:[{"createdOn":{$lte:"1712086400000"}},{"country": "India"},{"Type": "App"}]}';

// put quotes to all keys which start from $
json_str = json_str.replace(/\{(\$[a-zA-Z]+)\:/g,'{"$1":');

var obj = JSON.parse( json_str );

console.log( obj );
```